# Wick theorem and explicit vanishing of $\text{vacuum}\to e\bar{e}$

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, wick-theorem

I want to see explicitly how the transition amplitude for $\text{vacuum}\to e\bar{e}$ vanishes in QED but I'm struggling with Wick's theorem . I take $|i\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $|f\rangle=b^\dagger(\vec{p})d^\dagger(\vec{k})|0\rangle$, where $b^\dagger$ creates an electron and $d^\dagger$ a positron. The contribution to second order to the transition amplitude is

$$\langle f|\hat{T}_2|i\rangle=\frac{ie^2}{2}\!\int d^4x\!\int\! d^4y~\langle0 |b(\vec{p})d(\vec{k})\mathcal{T}\Big(\!\!:\!\bar{\psi}(x)\gamma^\mu\psi(x)A_{\mu}(x)\!:~\!\!:\!\bar{\psi}(y)\gamma^\nu\psi(y)A_{\nu}(y)\!:\!\!\Big)|0\rangle=\\=\frac{ie^2}{2}\!\int d^4x\!\int\! d^4y~(\gamma^\mu)_{ij}(\gamma^\nu)_{k\ell}G_{\mu\nu}(x-y)\langle0 |\mathcal{T}\Big(b(\vec{p})d(\vec{k})\!:\!\bar{\psi}_i(x)\psi_j(x)\!:~\!\!:\!\bar{\psi}_k(y)\psi_\ell(y)\!:\!\!\Big)|0\rangle$$

where $\mathcal{T}$ is time-ordering, $:\text{something}:$ is normal-ordering and $G_{\mu\nu}(x-y)$ the photon propagator.

Now I use Wick's theorem to make contractions appear (sorry for including a picture but I don't know how to write contractions here)

[image]

Since fermionic operators anticommute inside normal ordering, the exponents of $(-1)$ are:

1. First term: $1$ when moving $\bar{\psi}_i$ through $d$. $~2$ when moving $\bar{\psi}_k$ and $\psi_j$ through $\psi_\ell$
2. Second term: $3$ when moving $\bar{\psi}_k$ through $\psi_j$, $\bar{\psi}_i$ and $d$. $~1$ when moving $\psi_j$ through $\bar{\psi}_i$. $~1$ when anticommuting $\bar{\psi}_i$ and $\psi_\ell$ to construct the fermionic propagator

So the transition amplitude is

$$\langle f|\hat{T}_2|i\rangle=\frac{ie^2}{2}\!\int d^4x\!\int\! d^4y~G_{\mu\nu}(x-y)\Big(-\bar{u}(\vec{p},x)\gamma^\mu S_F(x-y)\gamma^\nu v(\vec{k},y)-\bar{u}(\vec{p},y)\gamma^\nu S_F(y-x)\gamma^\mu v(\vec{k},x)\Big),$$

but using that $G_{\mu\nu}(x-y)$ is symmetric in the indices and $x,y$ it doesn't vanish, so I must have missed a $-$ sign, but I can't see it.

Comment: Are the two terms supposed to cancel though? Many processes in QFT are forbidden kinetmically but allowed dynamically like $e \to e + \gamma$ . Off the top of my head, I don't think $\emptyset \to \phi + \phi$ vanishes either in $\phi^4$ theory to one-loop. There's a factor of $\delta(P_f - P_i)$ in front of the $T$-matrix term in the scattering amplitude that you haven't included.

Comment: @AfterShave Well, that delta araises naturally after writing everything explicitly and integrating over $x$, $y$ and the four-momentum of one of the propagators. In this case it's $\delta^{(4)}(k+p)$, which is $0$ for $p_0\neq 0 \neq k_0$, so now I see how this vanishes.

Comment: Do any of the other delta functions, the ones used to fix the momenta on the loops also evaluate to zero? I feel like it should be impossible to satisfy the internal momentum conservations as well and not just the overall one. I don't know, I'm just wondering about this. It seems like most textbooks don't pay much attention to these evidently impossible processes.

Comment: @AfterShave Two deltas show up when integrating over $x,y$, one of them is used when integrating the momentum of one of the propagators, and the other one is the overall four-momentum conservation. Then there is left an integral over all possible four-momentum for the other propagator.